# Trigger click in cross domain iFrame

Tags: jquery, iframe

I want to trigger a click event in a cross domain iframe.

For video embeds we are using images as cover for those iframes. When the image is clicked, the iframe gets loaded. This video embed has no autoplay function that can be used so we need to click the loaded embed to start the video.

We want to click the image, load the video embed(iframe) and have that iframe clicked again with jQuery.

Comment: show us your codes please.

Comment: That is not possible - you can't trigger click events **in** the iframe from the parent window because it would be a serious security issue if that's possible - imagine if a phishing site embeds an iframe from a shop and triggers a click for payment - what would you feel?

Comment: I am aware of the security issues. Was hoping that there might be another solution out there.

Comment: Is the iframed page under your control? postMessage would allow cross-domain communication, but you need to add code on both pages.

Comment: the iFramed page is not under our control.

Comment: Same issue. Any chance to find solution for this??? Need it badly

Comment: @DannyArntz: Then your answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.focus();//force focus on the currenct window;

window.addEventListener('blur', function(e){
    if(document.activeElement == document.getElementById('your_iframe_id'))
    {
        //do your stuff
    }
});

    $('your_iframe_id').mouseleave(function(){
        window.focus();
    });// double check when mouse out of iframe
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a way to perform it:

```
window.focus();
window.addEventListener('click', function(e){
 if(document.activeElement == document.getElementById('ve-panel-iframe'))
 {
    alert(1);
 }
});
```

Comment: What you're doing is catch a click but where4 do you forward it?